# Anyone got any idea what type of antenna these Wireless routers that have no "visible" dipole antenna on the outside use?

Tags: wireless, wifi, antenna

Referring to these type of wireless routers' antennae like : Netgear N150 and Linksys E1500

Comment: We should all open more devices and post photos of the internals on the internet.

Answer (score 4):

WiFi frequencies are high enough that useful antennas can be quite small.  It therefore isn't that hard to build the antennas into the case.  Here is a extreme example of a WiFi antenna built right onto the PC board of a WiFi module.  It can be seen near the top of the picture at the top right of the WiFi module.

[image]

The whole module from the ends of the solder pads on one side to the ends of the solder pads on the other side is about 1 inch.  The antenna itself is only about 13mm left to right in the picture.  The parts surrounding the WiFi module on the base board are 0805 packages.

Comment: Yes but what is exactly the difference in having an inbuilt antenna in a wireless router and having an antenna or two which are visible on the outside?

Comment: The external antennas will likely function better in that it is easier for the drive circuitry to use them to radiate the maximum allowed power.  Any amount of power can be radiated with any antenna, but the drive circuitry would be intractable and inefficient as the antenna gets too small.  In practise, a small PCB antenna as shown in the picture will have a bit less range than a larger external antenna with more convenient characteristics.  Units with built in antennas will have the drive circuitry and antenna matched, and may therefore still radiate the maximum allowed power.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, I have seen these antennas just as easy to match in many cases, it just has a larger loss in power. While a whip antenna(looks like a whip) has a gain to its sides, these often have atleast a 3 or 6 dB gain in their max direction.

Comment: Wish the antenna was circled in the picture. For a noob like me, not sure exactly which part is the antenna.

Comment: @Jake: As I said, it is at the top of the picture at the top right of the WiFi module.  It's the zig-zag trace.

Answer (score 2):

These on-board types of antennas are generally called ["microstrip"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microstrip) antennas, when used on the surface of the board.

Here's another example I've encountered recently, on a 2.4GHz zigbee devel board from TI:
[image: devel board]

(In this case there's no ground plane underneath, but I'm pretty sure it's still more or less the same category.)

Advantage is lower cost (fewer external components, cheaper assembly) at the expense of power handling.